# ⌈lg(n+1)⌉=⌊lgn⌋+1 floor and ceiling proof

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

I have assignment question which asks to prove one of the floor-ceiling property.
⌈lg(n+1)⌉=⌊lgn⌋+1

I have tried to prove using induction technique.
1. with n = 1 value, we get value 1 on both side.
2. we assume that it is true of n = k
3. We have to prove for n = k+1

I am stuck here, how to prove this third step.
Is there any other way to prove the same?
I understand that this is assignment question. Not answer but some hints will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a mathematics stack exchange where you may find your question more on topic.

Comment: yes here lg is log to the base 10

Answer (score 3):

I can prove that it's false. If `lg` is log<sub>10</sub>, and `n` is 99.5, then `ceil(lg(99.5+1))` is 3 while `floor(lg(99.5))+1` is 2, and your equality does not hold.

Comment: You could also have proven that it's false by assuming that `lg` is exp and `n` is a maple leaf.

Comment: I assumed that `lg` stood for an arbitrary logarithm, so I chose a specific example to make the point by contradiction. It does not seem to contradict the description of the problem.

Comment: `n` is probably intended to be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose lg is log10. For any n where 10^k <= n < 10^(k+1) - 1 for some integer k. k < lg(n+1)< k+1,that is ⌈lg(n+1)⌉ = k+1 and k =< lgn < k+1, then ⌊lgn⌋+1 = k+1. The equation will be true. 
Then, we just need specially handle the case where n=10^(k+1)-1, when n= 10^(k+1)-1, lg(n+1) = k+1, k < lgn < k+1, that is ⌊lgn⌋+1 = k+1. 
Above all,  ⌈lg(n+1)⌉=⌊lgn⌋+1 is always true for any integer n.